# Finding greatest element in series $1000^n/n!$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, functions

So the problem is to find the greatest element in the series

$$\frac{1000^n}{n!}$$

And what I did was simply to find for what values of $n$ the following inequality holds true:

$$\frac{1000^n}{n!}\le\frac{1000^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}$$

And the result is

$$n\le999$$

So this is indeed true according to Wolfram Alpha, and that $n_{999}=n_{1000}$. What I'm wondering is how to find the limit of the function $1000^n/n!$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ to confirm that the function doesn't diverge. Thanks.

Comment: Since $n!/1000^n \to \infty,$ there is no maximum.

Comment: Ohh I'm sorry, I wrote the fraction upside down... Now I fixed it.

Comment: For $n \geqslant 1999$, you have $\frac{1000^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \leqslant \frac{1}{2}\cdot \frac{1000^n}{n!}$. So $$\frac{1000^n}{n!} \leqslant \frac{1}{2^{n-1999}}\cdot \frac{1000^{1999}}{1999!}.$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Stirling’s approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling's_approximation)

$$n!\sim\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n$$

means that

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n}=1\;.$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1000^n}{n!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1000^n}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac{n}e\right)^n}=\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi}}\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{1000e}n\right)^n=0\;.$$